# java.xml.Validator: xsi:schlemaLocation is ignored when namespaces are present

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, xml-namespaces

I am currently trying to solve a (hopefully) simple problem, but I guess I am missing the obvious.

Self contained example code can be found over at [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/4fc5341c1cff57a5475b)

I am trying to validate an [XML document](https://raw.github.com/gist/29ff06c0720988d3d72a/b3f2deaa13bc2837504764b60b185267ffcaddc8/atomic.xml) that contains namespaces and an implicit schema location declaration with the help of Javas [Validator Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html).

The XML file looks like so (shortened for readability):

```
<atomic:root xmlns:atomic="qname123" xmlns:xsi="schemainstance" xsi:schemaLocation="atomic http://">
```

oXygen validates this XML against this implicit schema, yet I do not get it to work in my Code.

It works fine when validating documents without namespace, an example set of documents can be found at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/eca35d6fc42ccb20906c/3ed8aa791197b411cd1397270504a978106d4eff).

So obviously I am missing something, the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#newSchema%28%29) states that creating a newSchema() without parameters resorts the the location hints provided with the document.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, if you need more information let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found it out myself, it works perfectly when changing from:

```
<root xmlns:atomic="http://www.w3.org/XQueryTest"  xsi:schemaLocation="atomic atomic.xsd" />
```

to

```
<root  xmlns:atomic="http://www.w3.org/XQueryTest"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/XQueryTest atomic.xsd" />
```

Thanks anyway!